# Включение шаблона после контента страницы

Tags: шаблоны, mediawiki

На странице включается шаблон, далее следует контент страницы. Часть информации я бы хотел включить в первый шаблон, но выводить ее после контента страницы.
Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: У Вас вопрос в шапке с вопросом в теле сообщения немного расходится.

Comment: Не расходится. Часть информации должна выводиться после контента.

Comment: У Вас упоминание об информации для включени в первый шаблон. Следовательно есть Второй?  Вы хотите показывать часть информацию с первого шаблона после загрузки контента страницы. Тоесть информация 
 которая будет показываться не есть контент? Лучше всего всунуть в вопросе ваш проблемный код, а то на пальцах Вам мало что посоветуют.